# Editing an Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-logic-apps

I'm really new to Azure but I have created a streaming data set using Event Hubs, Streaming Jobs and Logic Apps.

It works but I want to change the recurrence interval of the Logic App from minutes to seconds. When I go into the Logic App and edit this the save button remains un-selectable. Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With standard plan I was able to "Save" the LA with recurrence of 15sec. which app service plan is your resource group associated with?

Comment: Hi I was able to get it down to 15 seconds by editing the code and then saving, for some reason the GUI method was not working. Do any service plans offer smaller granularity than 15 seconds?

Comment: Can you please share your codeview? Also which browser did you get this issue n did you try some other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2017, the recurrence should be able to be set to less than 15 seconds in code view. It is blocked in the visual designer as a safety precaution to prevent accidentally large bills.

[image: Setting recurrence in code]

However, a better approach might be to use the event hub trigger which will fire when events are available in your event hub. More information on creating an event hub trigger here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs